# Add blend Button to visual Studio project

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, blend

I draged style->simple button and copied the xml and placed in my visual studio xml every thing is resolved except one

```
<Button Content="Button" Margin="814,496,22,29" Style="{DynamicResource SimpleButton}"/>
```

xml gives error at DynamicResource and says not resource not found where as if i see this line by opening the solution made in blend and mouse over it says it is

```
MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.ReflectionTypeNode
```

so surely this is missing but cannot find it to add 
please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Blend project you should have a file called "Simple Styles.xaml". Copy it to your Visual Studio project and add reference to it in your App.xaml:

```
<Application
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="MyApplication.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Simple Styles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```